# Is this the right way to refactor? Anything better I can do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I've made an `Impressions` model, which keeps track of how many "views" a certain photo or event has. It tracks this by remote_url, remote_ip and user_agent. It works the way I want it.

Photos controller:

```
def show

  @photo.impressions.create(:request_url => request.url, :controller_name => controller_name, :action_name => action_name,
                            :ip_address => request.remote_ip, :user_agent => request.user_agent)
....
```

And my Events controller:

```
def show

  @event.impressions.create(:request_url => request.url, :controller_name => controller_name, :action_name => action_name,
                            :ip_address => request.remote_ip, :user_agent => request.user_agent)
....
```

However, I am thinking of refactoring this (to make the code cleaner). Perhaps creating a method in the `Photo` and `Event` models called `add_impression`. Which does exactly the same thing as above, but encapsulates the functionality of how impressions are created. It would look something like:

Photos controller:

```
def show

  @photo.add_impression(request.url, controller_name, action_name, request.remote_ip, request.user_agent)
....
```

And my Events controller:

```
def show

  @event.add_impression(request.url, controller_name, action_name, request.remote_ip, request.user_agent)
....
```

With this approach, I would end up with an add_impression method in the `Photo` and `Event` model. Not exactly DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). I'm considering creating an `Impression` module to tackle this.

Is this the right approach? Or is there something else that I should be doing?

**PS** Am not very well tuned with modules yet. So if anyone would like to leave a code snippet or links to articles worth reading. Please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would make Impression responsible for creating an impression with a class method, as such:

```
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.add_impression impressionable, options
    impressionable.impressions.create options
  end

end
```

Then in the controller:

```
Impression.add_impression @photo, options
```

Comment: By the way, is `options` a short-hand for something? Or, in my case should it be: `Impression.add_impression(@photo, request.url, controller_name, action_name, request.remote_ip, request.user_agent)`

Comment: I just put options as a placeholder, you would have to expand it for all the parameters. You may just want to pass controller_name, action_name and request as you can extract what you want from request in the method itself.